# Convert const char* type to int array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, mongodb

So I'm doing tests with the C++ MongoDB driver

Here is my test code

http://pastebin.com/eQUekQU2

In the code I make a small integer array and insert it into the mongo database as binary.

I retrieve the binary with this line of code as I traverse the rows

```
mongo::BSONElement array = obj["binTest"];
```

At this point I have the binary in this array variable which is of BSONElement type. I want to convert this binary back into an integer array. A function to do this can be seen in the api

http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_element.html#a8f4902eacf15f5069f4bb752bfd0aef4

Function Header

```
const char* mongo::BSONElement::binData (int &len)const
```

I want to run the function, get the binary data in const char* format and convert it into an int array. Can I caste it, or do I have to go every 4 bytes and put it into an array myself?

Thanks

Comment: what's the relationship between the char array and the int array.

Comment: The char array should just represent generic binary data that can be converted into whatever makes sense to you. Well that's what a unsigned char array usually resembles I'm not sure if this is unsigned or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you run the code on a hardware architecture with the same endianess (on PCs it is little-endianess), you can cast the retrieved char pointer to an int32 pointer and treat it as an int32 array.

However, if you have data exchange or cross-platform interoperability in your mind, it would be a bad idea to treat arrays of data types as byte arrays for storage/exchange purposes.

You would need to consider that different hardware platforms might have different endianess. In such cases, casting the char pointer to int32* would not work, and you would need to take the individual bytes and compose the int32 values. But it can become even trickier, because the endianess of the int32's written into the BSON-BinData is exactly the same endianess as the computer architecture the 'write code' was running on - which you would need to know to decode the binData again.

You would also need to consider that for arrays of other data types, casting might not work despite using the same hardware architecture. For example, the size of the *long* data type is different among the popular OS's for the Intel x86/x64 platform: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os